# Run docker-compose up in testNG beforesuite

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-compose, testng

I am looking for help/Suggestion about automating the docker-compose.yml file.

I have automated test scripts(testing xml suite) which verifies multiple micro API services, they are developed using Rest Assured, java and TestNG. Now these micro API services and DB are available on docker as image. 
Currently I am executing this automation while running this automation in following way

1. Making the docker-compose up
2. Waiting for the services to get up
3. Updating the end points in my configuration(Automation suite) which we see in docker container
4. And finally running the automation suite

I want to do all the above 4 points in one go as following. However unable to find any docs or anything open maven lib for it.

1. Run the docker-compose in beforeSuite method. Should work on all operating system wherever the docker and docker-compose is installed eg. Windows, centOS , linux, ubuntu
2. Once the services are up in docker container , it should update the end points in configuration file
3. Docker-compose down in aftersuite method

How we can achieve this or any kind open source lib available?

Comment: have you tried https://dmp.fabric8.io/ ?

Comment: Will check , thanks Francesco :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think [fabric8 docker-maven-plugin](https://dmp.fabric8.io/) suits your needs. You can run your it tests against containers you configure by docker-compose, dockerfile or plugin's configuration. I used the pluging in [this dummy project](https://github.com/fpezzati/Yomoka/). Have a look.